# CSS Pixel Perfection in Chrome

Tags: cross-browser, pixel, css, pixel-perfect

In pursuit of pixel perfection the browser seems to be adding an extra pixel to the top and bottom of the following input element but I can't figure out from where.

```
  input {
    border-radius: 10px;
    height:30px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    border:none;
    }
  }
```

Chromes magnifying glass shows the element with a total height of 32 and I'm trying to get 30.

It's a typical devise form coded in HAML:

```
.registration{:style => 'display:none'}
  = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
    %div
      = f.label :email do
        = f.email_field :email, :autofocus => false, :placeholder => "Email"
    %div
      = f.label :password do
        = f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Password'
    %div
      = f.label :password_confirmation do
        = f.password_field :password_confirmation, :placeholder =>'Confirm Password'
    %div= f.submit "Sign up"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take out padding:

```
input { padding: 0; }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nSmU9/

Update:

In Google Chrome, I see the height is 30px. [image]

Comment: This is definitely helpful but there is there is still one obnoxious pixel coming in from somewhere.